# Call function within object as parameter for a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

currently I'm extending my application, so I can give a directive (which generates a table grid) an object for additional buttons to show (for adding other other actions).

Now I can show the button but I need to execute some code as function which should be apply for a click on that button.

The object itself contains strings and function in a mixed way, like this:

```
<tablegrid
  table="flavorings"
  additional-buttons="[{name: 'add', onclick: 'function(){ }', icon: 'fa fa-plus'}]"
  show-actionbutton="true"
  show-rating="true"
  show-search="true"
  show-rowcheckbox="true"
  show-header="true">
</tablegrid>
```

My directive template looks like this:

```
<button ng-repeat="aB in additionalButtons" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ab.onclick" type="button">
  <i ng-class="aB.icon" ng-show="aB.icon  != ''" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
  <span>{{ 'TABLEGRID_'+aB.name | uppercase | translate }}</span>
</button>
```

How can I execute the onclick-function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call a function of an object of the scope in your view with:

```
ng-click="yourObject.functionName(parameters)"
```

*Don't forget the parenthesis in the function call even if there is no parameters*

Here is a demo of how it works:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.additionalButtons = [
        {'name': 'First', 
         'onclick': function() {alert('1')}
        }, 
        {'name': 'Second', 
         'onclick': function() {alert('2')}
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-repeat="ab in additionalButtons" ng-click="ab.onclick()">Click {{ab.name}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats works, thank you! But then I need to manually execute the function for the button itself, right? What would be the preferable way, eval()?
The function could contain AngularJS code and vanilla js.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*execute the function for the button itself*", could you elaborate?

Comment: I want to pass the additionalButtons object with n buttons, icon, name and the function which should be executed when I click the button.

The reason is, that I don't know the code of the specific function for the button within the directive cause I don't have generic actions (like adding new entires).

Even if I have generic actions like "add" I have to call the ab.onclick in the controller manually.

Hope you understand what I'm intended to do.

Comment: @Disane Not sure to understand. If you want to pass the whole object while clicking the button, just do `ng-click="onClick(additionalButtons)"`. But it seems to be a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)... *PS: Don't forget to check the mark if if helped :-)*

Comment: I dont want to pass the entire object to the function. The object is the number of buttons and the behavior for the onclick event. 

As you can see, in my directive template, I generate the buttons dynamically from the object which I passed to the directive. Every button should has its own function, name and icons (which works actually) which is defined in the object I pass through the directive.

Unfortunately, my question has not yet been answered.

Comment: That looks better! But, in my case I need the declaration of "additionalButtons" within the template, since I don't have a special controller for the pages. Or would you declare them in a special controllers for that page? What would be the best practise for this?

Comment: @Disane It is always cleaner to move the logic to a controller. Avoid doing it in your HTML.  ["*Divide and conquer*"](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj7wqPx1_7VAhWCuhoKHUzVBzIQFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Factivelamp.com%2Fblog%2Fdevelopment%2Fdivide-and-conquer-part-1%2F&usg=AFQjCNGBLejj0aZks7rctECI0tDSuI_vmQ)

Comment: ok, now my answer has been answered, thank you for your time and sorry for the misunderstanding at the beginning :)